# Grails Facebook Login using spring security - how to know logged in user name

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

In a Grails application, with spring security facebook plugin, when user logs in, how can the application get actual facebook user name so that the home page can display the logged in user name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plugin provides Facebook API `access_token`, and you have to request such user details from Facebook.

**Example:**

Add dependency to Spring Social Facebook:

```
dependency {
  compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

and then load it from Facebook on user creation, by adding following into FacebookAuthService:

```
void onCreate(FacebookUser user, FacebookAuthToken token) {
  Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
  FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile

  //fill the name
  //fieldname ('fullname' at this example) is up to you
  user.fullname = fbProfile.name
}
```

See also

- docs for Spring Social - http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html#facebook-getProfile
- about FacebookUserService - http://splix.github.com/grails-spring-security-facebook/guide/5%20Customization.html#5.1%20Using%20FacebookAuthService

Comment: Thanks!. Really appreciate your prompt/detailed response and help.

Comment: I am new in Grails. Where I have to put `void onCreate(FacebookUser user, FacebookAuthToken token)` action in my grails application

Comment: You have to implement FacebookAuthService, and put it here