# How to fetch Facebook UserName, Email, phoneno etc from Facebook Authentication for Spring Security in Grails

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using [Spring Security Core Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) for Authentication purpose and [Facebook Authentication for Spring Security](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) for Facebook login purpose. My FB login works fine with Spring Security Plugin. But I have some issue on that. How Can I fetch UserName, Email, phoneno etc of Facebook user so that I can save it to my db.

Here is my Spring Security Core Person.groovy Domain Class file ...

```
class Person {

transient springSecurityService

String realName
String username
String password
boolean enabled
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired
byte[] avatar
String avatarType
    ...... more code ...........
}
```

Here You can see I added some more fields like realName(for saving facebook user name), avatar(for saving facebook user profile image) etc. Right now Username is saving like this `facebook_100003641451723`. I want the real name of user so that i can save it to my realName field. Any idea how can i do this ??

**UPDATE :**

I found one solution over there [Grails Facebook Login using spring security - how to know logged in user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151717/grails-facebook-login-using-spring-security-how-to-know-logged-in-user-name)

But I don't know where I put this code ...

```
void onCreate(FacebookUser user, FacebookAuthToken token) {
  Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
  FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile

  //fill the name
  //fieldname ('fullname' at this example) is up to you
  user.realName = fbProfile.name
 }
```

**UPDATE :**

Now I created new service by running `grails create-service FacebookAuthService` and my FacebookAuthService.groovy is created inside services/groovypublish/FacebookAuthService.groovy there..

Here is my FacebookAuthService.groovy file ..

```
package groovypublish

import org.grails.twitter.Person
import com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthToken


class FacebookAuthService {

   def serviceMethod() {

   }

   void onCreate(Person user, FacebookAuthToken token) {
   Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
   FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile

   //fill the name
   //fieldname ('fullname' at this example) is up to you
   user.realName = fbProfile.name
  }

  }
```

and I put dependencies in my BuildConfig.groovy file ....

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
     compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
     compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Now When i start my grails application `grails run-app` it showing error

```
     C:\Users\Shreshtt\workspace\groovypublish\grails-app\services\groovypublish\FacebookAuthService.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class Facebook @ line 14, column 12.
 Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
          ^

     C:\Users\Shreshtt\workspace\groovypublish\grails-app\services\groovypublish\FacebookAuthService.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class FacebookTemplate @ line 14, column 23.
 Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
                     ^

     C:\Users\Shreshtt\workspace\groovypublish\grails-app\services\groovypublish\FacebookAuthService.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class FacebookProfile @ line 15, column 19.
 FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile
                 ^

 3 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it into your implementation of [FacebookAuthService](http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/#customization).

Just create service with such name, and add method `onCreate` with this code (or similar). And don't forget ot add Spring Social Facebook as a dependency

Comment: I don't know after click on FB login button, which action is to be called. I still don't understand where I will put `def FacebookAuthService`..

Comment: It's a service, standard Grails service: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html

Comment: My grails-app/services folder is empty. Do I have to create new service by running this command `grails create-service FacebookAuthService`

Comment: You have to import this classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: I could not find Facebook and FacebookProfile classes. Which file i have to import for that

Comment: Have you define call back URL in the Facebook app ?

Comment: Could you solve your problem?? If ypu couldnt, let me know and I will post a full answer to this

Comment: URL is broken. You should include main parts of the solution here to avoid these scenarios..

Comment: main part is "implement FacebookAuthService" :) link is fixed, btw

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you should **Oauth plugin**, check it out here : http://grails.org/plugin/oauth
I am developing a Grails project using this plugin, my project includes Facebook authenticaton, and now its working fine.